# Can PSNR > 48 used to validate the signals between two audio files?

Tags: matlab, audio, mp3

I have written some audio decoding code. I decoded an mp3 file and save as wav file.

In order to validate the code is working correctly, I compare the signal between the mp3 file and the decoded audio in wav file by using PSNR matlab (coding shown below).
The results obtained are shown in the table.

```
Signal1 = audio.mp3;
Signal2= audio.wav;
[R C]=size(Signal1);
err = sum((Signal1 -Signal2).^2)/(R*C); 
MSE=sqrt(err);
MAXVAL=255;
PSNR = 20*log10(MAXVAL/MSE);
```

[image: PSNR Result]

How can I comment on the result?

According to the post [here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_are_the_max_and_min_values_of_SNR_PSNR_Can_be_the_values_greater_than_40dB5), it says ‘**If the reconstructed audio signal is exactly same as original signal then MSE =0. And if Max pixel value is 255 (8-bit representation), then the value of PSNR = 20*log(255) = 48dB**.’

Since the PSNR of the songs are more than 48, can I conclude that the decoded audio signal in the wav file is valid?

Comment: um, where does you MAXVAL come from? I doubt it's right.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, if Max pixel value is 255 (8-bit representation), then the value of PSNR = 20*log(255) = 48dB. This is the maximum value of PSNR when signal is represented in 8-bits.

Comment: ... that is just repeating what's in your question. What I meant to ask is "how do you know your maximum value is 255? That sounds wrong!".

Comment: Audio doesn't have pixels and typically doesn't work with 8-bit (unless it's really bad audio)

Comment: If the MSE is zero, then the PSRN would be infinite

Comment: @MarcusMüller, because my audio file is in uint8 data. So the default value of peakval / maxval is 255.

Comment: if your audio file is uint8, it's inherently never going to be very high PSNR. the best you can theoretically say would be that it's "within 8 bits of precision of the original audio", but the original audio wasn't 8 bits, so that's kind of a less-than-useful measure.

Comment: Anyway, the statement is plain wrong. Assume perfect reconstruction. That means MSE=0. When you divide by 0, you get infiinity, and not 48 dB.

Answer (score 1):

> If the reconstructed audio signal is exactly same as original signal then MSE =0. And if Max pixel value is 255 (8-bit representation), then the value of PSNR = 20*log(255) = 48dB

That statement is plain wrong. If the two signals are identical, then MSE = 0, then division by zero is undefinied and you don't get a PSNR at all, but "infinity".

> Since the PSNR of the songs are more than 48, can I conclude that the decoded audio signal in the wav file is valid?

PSNR is really not a very useful metric; you can get these values with a codec that simply broken, or one that sounds great.

Let's throw a bit of math in here: let's say we map our 8 bit to - to +1. Our original audio signal $S$ is well-scaled and its amplitude is pretty normally distributed¹, centered around 0, and has a variance $\sigma^2=\frac14$, so that clipping very rarely happens, i.e. $S\sim\mathcal N(0;\frac14)$.

Then, what's the PSNR of a codec that simply always produces "0"?

\begin{align}
\text{PSNR} &= 20\log_{10}\left(\frac{\text{Maxval}}{\sqrt{\text{MSE}}}\right)\\
&=20\log_{10}\left(\frac{\text{1}}{\sqrt{\text{MSE}}}\right)\\
&=10\log_{10}\left(\frac{\text{1}}{\sqrt{\text{MSE}}}\right)^2\\
&=10\log_{10}\left(\frac{\text{1}}{\text{MSE}}\right)\\
\end{align}

So, what's our MSE? It is

\begin{align}
\mathbb E\left((0-S)^2\right)&= \mathbb E\left( S^2\right)\\
&S \text{ is zero-mean}\\
&=\text{Var}\{S\}=\sigma^2\\
&=\frac14
\end{align}

Therefore,

\begin{align}
\text{PSNR} &= 10\log_{10}(4) \\
&\approx 6
\end{align}

So, what this would prove is that your codec is *better* than just producing the mean value of the information-theoretically worst possible continuous audio source – but that's about it.

---

¹ that assumption about the amplitude distribution is slightly wrong, but wrong in favor of your codec.